MobaXterm: Upon first opening MobaXterm, Start specific sessions automatically
Is there a way when MobaXterm is first started for it to start specific sessions automatically?
I find that every time I open the app I always access the same 4 systems every time. Instead of having to click on each one and execute, can MobaXterm do it when its opened?
